# Use Gradle classes as application code?

Tags: java, testing, gradle

... or indeed as testing code?

It just seems to me that there are multiple cases in a typical project and its testing arrangements which naturally involve Projects, Tasks and dependencies.

Even on a trivial level, I've sometimes found that preparing the ground between one test and the next it is necessary to clear out directories / repopulate them... and in Gradle (or Ant for that matter) there are methods that do that with little fuss...

Is there any reason NOT to contemplate using these classes in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a viable idea to me - after all, the Gradle classes represent a public API (even though it is typically consumed through their DSL), so as long as you keep using them for their intended purpose, you should be fine. However, there may be a lot of internal logic in the classes that is tied to the typical Gradle workflows, so you might find that once you "step outside the trodden path" and try to do things in a sequence Gradle doesn't expect, you might find yourself in trouble.

Comment: Thanks.  True... I suppose the flip side of this is that imposing the disciplines and conventions of the "Gradle way" might make for more maintainable code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [doc section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html) on embedding Gradle. Quote:

> The main audience for this API is IDE, CI server, other UI authors;
>   however, the API is open for anyone who needs to embed Gradle in their
>   application.

Admittedly, this talks more about *builds* than *tasks*, but it seems germane to the investigation.

Comment: Thanks.A second ago I awarded the "accepted answer" to Aasmund.  But it's one of those situations where I feel terrible not awarding jointly to both of you!  Still, you have (at time of writing) a 10.5k rep, so maybe you won't be too annoyed.